# Calculating percent of authorship in TFS repository

Tags: tfs

Is there any plug-in to TFS or Visual Studio which calculates the percent of authorship? I mean a metric that aims at quantifying the contribution of each developer. I vaguely remember that something like that exists in Tortoise SVN.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the Code Churn [report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244661.aspx)